# How to unlock screen in Kubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, lock

After upgrading to Kubuntu 11.10, I'm no longer able to unlock my screen.  The screen stays blank.  Oddly, it seems I'm able to logout of my current session by hitting Ctrl-Alt-Delete Enter.  Any advice?

Comment: I have the same issue. I can ctrl+alt+F1 and log in to the command line to issue a reboot, which is at least better than a hard reset. It appears that the mouse cursor changes when I mouse up and down over the username and password fields, but I am not able to log in if I type my password and press enter. I end up rebooting every time.

Comment: If you remove the password protect from your screensaver, does the problem still exist? Does it exist using some other screen saver? I use the slideshow screensaver (with no password), and it takes some time, about 5-10 seconds, before the screensaver aborts and I can resume using the computer.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with 11.04 using the latest KDE. It would appear that the dialogue is somehow blocked by the screen saver. If you hit a button to invoke the login dialogue and type your password followed by enter the screen should unlock.

Comment: It looks like I'm able to unlock (the mouse pointer will change depending upon what window is under it) but the screen is still blank.

Comment: oi, what video card and drivers are you using?